# Given $\displaystyle f(x,y) = \frac{\sin (xy)}{x}$, $x \neq 0$, make $f(0,y)$ continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following question. Let $\displaystyle f(x,y) = \frac{\sin (xy)}{x}$, define $f(0,y)$ to be continuous. The function is not defined at $x = 0$, so I need to make $\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}$ continuous at $x = 0$. How can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(xy)}{x} = y\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}$.

Answer (score 1):

You know (or should know) that $\frac{\sin x}{x}\to1$ as $x\to0$.  The choice of how to define $f(0,y)$ should now be obvious.

Also note,

$$\left|\frac{\sin(xy)}{x}\right|\leq\frac{|xy|}{|y|}=|x|\to0\;\text{as}\;x\to0.$$